# DC motor coupled to a DC generator

Tags: dc-motor, generator, speed

Consider a separately excited DC motor which is coupled to a shunt dc generator (under no load condition) and acts as a prime mover. If we set the speed of the DC motor to some certain value (for example 1500 rpm) and increase the field current of the generator, there is a slight reduction in the DC motor's speed. What's the reason for this? Is this related to the armature reaction?

I couldn't find the reason in the textbooks or on the Internet.

Comment: That is the law of the nature, [law of Conservation of Energy and efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy).

Comment: @jay Would you explain more, please? I'm aware of the law of conservation of energy but how is this related to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a DC generator is turned, the voltage generated depends on the product of field current and rotation rate.

The internal losses in the generator (capacitive, eddy currents; arcing at the commutator) will increase at higher voltages (even at a fixed rotation rate). This will reflect as a slightly higher load on the motor.

Comment: Would you explain how the increase of internal losses leads to the reduction in motor's speed, please?

Comment: The last sentence explains it.  Higher load on the motor.  Look at the torque-speed curve of the motor.

Comment: #1 @S.H.W.. So.. smile first .. :-) since I remember I suggested my great idea to my father (educator, self-established scientist) when I was.. might be 7. I did the experiment along with my daddy's fund and help as well. First, the speed is not all you need to measure to understand the "efficiency" and "lose". Here: DC motor took energy from line (electricity) -> Motor convert the "electric energy" to "physical energy" (speed, torque, power, force) + lose, that lose coming from the imperfection due to the "nature" of the motor (nature: I want you to

Comment: #2 @S.H.W... (nature: I want you to study about the motor, before trying to build a perpetual machine) -> the physical energy is delivered to the generator as a form of torque (force) -> generator cannot run free without lose due to the "nature" of the generator -> generator loads (burdens) motor to ride on -> The motor exchange the speed with the loaded torque, thus slows down (speed and torque relationship). Good luck with your research!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused because an increment of generator field should rise generator voltage output, and this will cause also a motor speed increment. I can find 2 reasons that can explain the motor speed reduction:

1. If generator field is connected to generator armature, and it is working in magnetic saturation, then an increment of voltage will generate a low increment of magnetic field (and output voltage is proportional to magnetic field), but on the other hand will increase generator load. The balance could reduced voltage.
2. If both motor field and armature are connected to generator output, an increment in voltage should increase motor speed, but also motor field current will increase and this can reduce motor speed (no load speed n0=k*E/Flux). It depends on motor parameters.

Check what happens with generator voltage in your trial.